# What weapons are paintable with War Paint?

Tags: team-fortress-2

For example, is the Classic paintable with the Jungle Inferno War Paints?

If not, which other weapons are not paintable?

Comment: You know you can check this yourself from the Items screen, War Paints button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list for all possible paintable items, by class:

Scout:

- Scattergun
- Shortstop
- Soda Popper
- Winger
- Holy Mackerel

Soldier:

- Rocket Launcher
- Air Strike
- Black Box
- Reserve Shooter
- Disciplinary Action

Pyro

- Flamethrower (stock)
- Degreaser
- Detonator
- Reserve Shooter
- Scorch Shot
- Back Scratcher
- Powerjack

Demoman:

- Grenade launcher (stock)
- Iron Bomber
- Loch n Load
- Loose Cannon
- Stickybomb launcher (stock)
- Claidheamh Mor
- Persian Persuader
- Scotsman's Skullcutter

Heavy:

- Minigun (stock)
- Brass Beast
- Tomislav
- Family Business

Engineer:

- Rescue Ranger
- Wrench (stock)
- Jag

Medic:

- Crossbow
- Medigun (stock)
- Amputator
- Ubersaw

Sniper:

- Sniper Rifle (stock)
- Bazaar Bargain
- SMG (stock)
- Shahanshah

Spy:

- Revolver (stock)
- Knife (stock)

Multi-class:

- Shotgun
- Panic Attack
- Pistol

A couple notes:

- Dragon's Fury (new pyro flamer) is not in this list, as it only accepts one paint (the Dragon Slayer one). However, I'm pretty sure this paint can be obtained from a contract with the campaign pass, so it's elite grade isn't that big of an issue.
- As of now, all listed weapons seem to be able to accept any paint.
- [See the TF2 wiki for a list of paints from these cases.](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/War_Paint#Skins_from_the_Jungle_Jackpot_War_Paint_Collection)

Comment: hopefully in future updates more weapons will be added

Comment: @DanielFox yep, it would be really nice to have more paintable weapons, like the big earner or ambi.